# How to read text file and insert to database

Tags: sql, text, vbscript, sql-insert

I have lot of text file with content below:

```
LOG_NAME=LOGX1245;
LOT_NO=NA;
STEP=NA;
NO=CS84E869500115;
TIME_START=20190506 094715;
TIME_END=20190506 094715
```

I need to read the text file and insert to database.
The column name is the first field and value is the second field.
How to read the text file and insert each of lines to database?

What I do is:

```vb
For Each file In fso.GetFolder("C:\Data").Files
    Set otf = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file, 1)
    Do Until otf.AtEndOfStream
        line = otf.ReadLine

        If Mid(line, 1, 12) = "LOG_NAME" Then
            datalog = Trim(Split(line, "=")(1))
        End If

        If Mid(line, 1, 10) = "LOT_NO" Then
            PT = Trim(Split(line, "=")(1))
        End If

        If Mid(line, 1, 4) = "STEP" Then
            TestStep = Trim(Split(line, "=")(1))
        End If

        If Mid(line, 1, 11) = "NO" Then ...
    Loop
    otf.Close
Next
```

This is where I want to query. How to query the SQL INSERT statement based on value that I get from text file? Is there any simpler way?

```vb
Dim query
Set rsObj = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

query = "Insert in"

On Error Resume Next
rsObj.Open query, connObj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\Data.accdb"

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\Data").Files
    Set objDataFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, 1)
    arrData = Split(objDataFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine) 'store file data in array
    objDataFile.Close

    varValues = Empty: varFields = Empty
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        arrRowData = Split(arrData(i), "=")
        varFields = varFields & "[" & arrRowData(0) & "]," 'square bracket to avoid reserve keyword as field name
        arrRowData(1) = Left(arrRowData(1), Len(arrRowData(1)) - 1) 'remove last semicolon
        varValues = varValues & "'" & arrRowData(1) & "',"
    Next
    varFields = Left(varFields, Len(varFields) - 1) 'remove last comma
    varValues = Left(varValues, Len(varValues) - 1) 'remove last comma
    objConn.Execute "INSERT INTO Data(" & varFields & ") VALUES(" & varValues & ")"
Next

Set objFSO = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
```

I have used an Access DB to test the code. Also, I assumed that the text file in Data folder are similar and they only contain data suitable for database insertion.

DB before running the code

[image]

DB after running the code

[image]

I tested with 2 text files in Data folder.

Comment: i also want to get the column name too. 
`varCol = Empty
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        varData = Split(arrData(i), "=")(0) 'get just the data part
        msgbox varData
        varCol = varCol  & varData & ","
msgbox varCol  
    Next
 varCol = Left(varCol, Len(varCol) - 1) 'remove last semicolon
 msgbox varCol
 
    objConn.Execute "INSERT INTO Data (" & varCol & ") VALUES (" & varValues & ")"`

Comment: may i know on how to shcek if each of the insert query successfully executed? i had tried `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` , if meet the condition, then query error.  but it return true even tough query successfully inserted.